# New parent directory breaks Git for Windows commit. How fix?

Tags: git

I have a large code directory tree, T, running on Windows 11 locally. The same T exists on a Linux cloud server. When I edit files in T locally I use Git for Windows (GFW) to update T on the cloud. I've been doing this for years with no problem.

Recently I reorganized the directory structure on my local machine. Now T sits under a new directory N. Since this change, GFW is unable to properly execute the command

```bash
$ git commit -a
```

I get an error message like this:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe: line 1: C:Program: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

My guess is that the T/.git directory, created before the recent directory reorganization, needs to be updated or regenerated, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Please advise.

UPDATE
When I carry out the following command in GFW the problem persists:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "\\"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe\""

$ git config --global core.editor
"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
```

Comment: Because `C:\Program Files` has a space in it, it needs to be in quotes. When you set `EDITOR`/`VISUAL`/etc, make sure it contains those quotes (or make sure `sublime_text.exe` is in a location in your `PATH`, and set the editor configuration to not same its file location at all). This has nothing to do with your directory structure changes.

Comment: Did you move T into a directory which already has a .git directory with a different configuration than T?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I respectfully disagree. If I need to introduce quotes and so on, why was everything working perfectly, for years, until the moment I changed the directory structure?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, there is not a second .git directory.

Comment: For context, this issue has to do with your git configuration, and not with the repo itself per-se. The problem is that you 1) tried to create a commit without specifying a commit message, so 2) git tried to open a text editor to let you specify the commit message, but 3) opening the text editor failed. From the error output, we can see that the configured text editor is `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe`, which resulted in git trying to run `C:Program`. That _strongly_ suggests that this is a quoting issue as Charles Duffy said

Comment: @Argent Does running `git config --list --show-origin` show which file git is getting `core.editor` from?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Please see my update, above.

Comment: @Argent Could you include of output of the command from above? git may not be using the global value if a configuration from a different file is taking precedence

Comment: @Brian61354270 Can I email you the output? When I try to put it into the narrow format of Stack Overflow it's an unreadable mess.

Comment: @Argent You can surround the command output with triple-backticks ````(```)```` to format it as a scrollable code block. I think only lines containing `core.editor` are relevant. Also, be sure to run the command from inside the repo

Comment: You could also try setting `core.editor` to a dummy value and see if the error message updates to match.

Comment: What I suggested was to set your editor to _just_ `sublime_text.exe` and configure your PATH to include `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. In short, it required deleting the old .git directory and generating a new one. In my repo:

```
rd .git /s/q
git init
git add --all
```

As suggested by Charles Duffy, I put the sublime_text.exe directory into the Windows system PATH. I then ran

```
git config --global core.editor "sublime_text.exe -w"
```

The -w is a sublime_text.exe flag: Wait for the file to be closed before returning.

```
git commit
```

This brings up the editor, which was the problem I was trying to solve. I then uncommented all the "new" files and saved. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This error, as mentioned in the comments, relates to the git configuration for the editor. To change the global editor and make sure this config isn't being overwritten by a local config, run the following:

```bash
git config --unset --local core.editor
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Path\To\Executable.exe'"
```

Alternatively, you can commit without opening the text editor by using the `-m` flag:

```bash
git commit -m "Your commit message here"
```